# Flutter Federated Plugins - Default Method Channel Implementation

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I've been going over documentation and examples of federated plugins from the official flutter/packages repo on GitHub. I see several plugins implement a `MethodChannel[Plugin]Platform` implementation but I don't quite understand why. None of the platform specific packages seem to use these. Are these just for running tests?

General question. I just want to know the reasoning behind these implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah okay, I think I found my own answer in some of the docblocks. It looks like those are created by plugin authors whose plugins predate the federated strategy and offer backwards compatibility for anyone who relied on those method channels.